# Implementation of std::unique_ptr<T[]>::reset in gcc 6

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, unique-ptr, gcc6

Since GCC 6 in C++ the declaration/definition of a `unique_ptr<T[]>::reset` method (not the one, that accepts only `nullptr_t`) looks like this:

```
template <typename _Up,
            typename = _Require<
              __or_<is_same<_Up, pointer>,
                    __and_<is_same<pointer, element_type*>,
                           is_pointer<_Up>,
                           is_convertible<
                             typename remove_pointer<_Up>::type(*)[],
                             element_type(*)[]
                           >
                    >
              >
           >>
  void
  reset(_Up __p) noexcept
  {
using std::swap;
swap(std::get<0>(_M_t), __p);
if (__p != nullptr)
  get_deleter()(__p);
  }
```

This was changed at some point to implement [N4089](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4089.pdf). According to that document:

> This function behaves the same as the reset member of the primary template, except that it
>   shall not participate in overload resolution unless either
>
> — `U` is the same type as `pointer`, or
>
> — `pointer` is the same type as `element_type*`, `U` is a pointer type `V*`, and `V(*)[]` is convertible to `element_type(*)[]`.

Let's consider the following example:

```
std::unique_ptr<const char []> ptr1;
std::unique_ptr<char []> ptr2(new char[5]);
ptr1 = std::move(ptr2);
```

Since version 6 GCC produces an error, complaining that it cannot call `std::swap` with `const char*&` and `char*&`. 
`reset` method takes place in the overload resolution as `char[]` is convertible to `const char[]`, but naturally `std::swap` awaits two references of the same type.

Is this considered to be a correct behavior? If so, then why? If I can implicitly convert `char[]` to `const char[]`, why the same should not be possible with `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Seems like a gcc bug, filed [77987](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77987)

Comment: Looks like [Jon Wakely](http://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) is already fixing it.

Comment: Greate! So it really was a bug. Thx @Barry for filing. I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this really seems to be a bug in gcc libstdc++.
@Barry has reported it: [77987](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77987)